# Repair Local Visual Studio TFS Workspace Mapping

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have managed to corrupt my local Visual Studio Team Foundation Server workspace mappings.  Visual Studio can successfully connect to TFS and I can manage the TFS Server connections.  However, I cannot open Source Control Explorer or the Workspaces/Manage Workspaces dialogue.  Both windows fail with the following message: "Error Unexpected end of file.".  From my local machine I also cannot get any information about my workspaces from the tf.exe command line which fails with the same error message "Unexpected end of file."

I would like to note that TFS/database still has my workspaces mapped correctly since I can successfully retrieve information about them from a different machine.

I would like to repair or remove whatever local file Visual Studio is using to map the workspaces.  Does anyone know where this information is stored?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've fixed my issue where Visual Studio was unable to open Source Control Explorer and Workspaces/Manage Workspaces dialogue by deleting the cache folder located here at:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Once this folder was deleted reopening Visual Studio was able to connect to Source Control Explorer and I can once again manage my workspaces from the IDE. (Visual Studio created a new cache folder in the same location after starting)

Comment: thanks! was going nuts.  This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, in vs2015 its located under Team Foundation\6.0\Cache

Comment: This is for vs2017 %localappdata%l\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache thanks you saved the day

Comment: I was having an issue after IT renamed my laptop computer name on the domain, nothing I did would fix it, until I blew the cache folders away. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thank you !! This solution worked for me, in the visual studio 2022 - AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache