# Not able to Map Workspace in local folder using VS 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, workspace

I was trying to map workspace, due to some issue I have canceled the process and deleted the entry from Manage Workspace.
But when I retried the process, I am getting below error

```
"The workspace [workspaceName];[Owner] already exists on computer [ComputerName]"
```

I have tried below things to resolve it

1) using VS Command prompt

```
First display list of workspaces for named computer giving workspace name and owner:

>tf  workspaces /computer:oldComputerName /collection:”http://devsrvr:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection&#8221;



To delete:

>tf workspace /delete WorkSpaceName;OwnerName /collection:”http://devsrvr:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection&#8221;
```

But listing command is not showing any workspace. so this option dosen't help me.
I got the help reference form [here](https://tatvog.wordpress.com/2016/07/27/tfs-the-workspace-already-exists-on-computer/)

2) Tried Repair Local Visual Studio TFS Workspace Mapping by clearing cache data from `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`. This option also didn't work for me. I am still getting same error. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429753/repair-local-visual-studio-tfs-workspace-mapping)

3) Checked `Control Panel >> User Account >> Mange Password` for deleted the enetries (It is used to work with older VS version). But this also didn't work.

Please let me know if any one know the resolution.

Comment: Are you able to create a workspace with new name? Are you able to delete the working folder manually?

Comment: Yes I am able to create a workspace with new name. The issue got resolved by it.

Comment: @SKiran, Would you please mark the helpful reply as the answer if this issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the items below:

1. Close VS.
2. Removes the specified workspace entry with the command line: `tf workspaces /remove:(*|workspace1[,workspace2,...]) /collection:(*|TeamProjectCollectionUrl)`
3. Delete the workspace with command `tf workspace /delete [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] workspacename[;workspaceowner] [/login:username,[password]]`
4. Create a workspace with new name and then retry deleting the old workspace.

Comment: I have tried list it using

tf  workspaces /computer:oldComputerName /collection:”http://devsrvr:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection&#8221;

But it is not showing any workspace.

Comment: It worked, It was configured on old computer. Since I was not having access to delete the old one, I just configured with new name. ;)